Cannot understand the stereospecificity and stereoselectivity of a compound formed in a reaction
How is the reaction given below stereospecific and stereoselective?
1,3,6-trimethylcyclohexene is treated with B2H6 followed by H2O2/NaOH/H2O.

Since trans and cis form in cycloalkene starts in a 8 membered ring so the given compound doesn't show cis trans forms so after hydroboration shouldn't a racemic mixture be formed, which is not stereoselective. And still can't understand why is it stereospecific.

https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/reaction-guide/hydroboration-of-alkenes/ explains where the hydroxyl group is added, and that the addition is syn rather than anti.

Nancy, welcome to ChemSE. I presume you have read @Karstens link and you understand the basics of hydroboration. The presumption is that 1,3,6-trimethylcyclohex-1-ene (1), as shown, is racemic because it lacks any descriptor such as (3R,6R) to indicate that it is a single enantiomer. In which case, all derived cyclohexanols will be racemic.
As to terminology there are two terms to be considered: regioselective and stereoselective. Regioselective addresses where the hydroxyl group goes. Clearly, generic structure 2 will dominate over 3. Let's look at structure 2 in more detail. Given the syn-hydroboration of the double bond and the subsequent transformation of the C-B bond to C-O with retention of configuration, the two racemic stereoisomers, 4 and 5, are possible. As to which stereoisomer predominates, that is a discussion for another day. For the sake of argument, let's say that 4 dominates over 5. Then the reaction is said to be stereoselective. Various modifiers may be applied such as highly stereoselective (90/10) or moderately stereoselective (60/40).
Notice that the term stereospecific was not mentioned. That is because it does not apply in this example. A stereospecific reaction is mechanism controlled wherein two stereoisomers afford two different stereoisomers. Consider the hydroboration of achiral (Z)-6. This reaction produces racemic alcohol 7, whereas (E)-9 affords stereoisomeric racemic alcohol 8. Likewise, the anti bromination and syn peracid epoxidation of alkenes 6 and 9 are stereospecific.

